# Include sub-element inside JSF 2.0 component

Tags: java, jsf, components, wrapper, parameter-passing

This must be simple. I am trying to pass sub-element into a JSF component. I have my component declared as:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <ui:insert />
    </div>
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

Then I use this in a page by:

```
<box:box>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</box:box>
```

Unfortunately, the box renders ok (the black border) but the "Hello world!" text is not included within it. I also tried more verbose syntax by using `<ui:insert name="content">` and calling by `<ui:define name="content">Hello World!</ui:define>` but it didn't work.

Where might I be making a mistake?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. You should use [`<composite:insertChildren />`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/insertChildren.html) instead as in:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <composite:insertChildren />
    </div>
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the content as parameter:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
         <composite:attribute name="content"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
             <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.content}" escape="false"/>
        </div>
    </composite:implementation>

</html>
```

and in your code:

```
<box:box content="<p>Hello world!</p>" />
```

I added the `escape="false"` since you are using HTML tags inside the EL expression.

Read more about composite elements in [David Geary’s article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html)

Comment: Yes this would be one way to do that but it's very ugly design. Also, what if I have a longer section of XHTML/JSF code that I want to use as sub-element? Passing the content as string attribute is unconvenient. Instead, the style I tried (using `<ui:insert />`) should work, as lined in http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-composition-components-in-jsf-2.0 (look at the chapter "Passing sub-elements to composition components"). This same approach is also covered in book JSF 2 APIs and JBoss Seam. However, in my tests it fails.