# Passing markup via composite components attributes

Tags: attributes, jsf-2, facelets, markup, composite-component

Is there a way to pass markup (in opposite to plain text) via composite
component's attributes? Simply `<composite:insertChildren>` won't suffice, 
since the component rely on distinct text parameters. Passing tags via 
attributes as described in [Include sub-element inside JSF 2.0 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474727/include-sub-element-inside-jsf-2-0-component) does not work (invalid attribute content).

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare it as [`<cc:facet>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/facet.html) and render it as [`<cc:renderFacet>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/renderFacet.html):

```html
<cc:interface>
    <cc:facet name="foo" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <cc:renderFacet name="foo" />
</cc:implementation>
```

This way you can specify it using [`<f:facet>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/facet.html):

```html
<my:composite>
    <f:facet name="foo">
        <p>Some <strong>HTML</strong> markup.</p>
    </f:facet>
</my:composite>
```

Comment: Thank you, BalusC. To sum up: Facets are intended to supply literal content for rendering, while attributes are mere function parameters?